# Regex matching string followed by specific numbers

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have a list:

```
gform_18
gform_27
gform_23
gform_11
```

Let's say I'd like my regex to match "gform_" when it's followed by numbers 18, 23, and 11. 27 has to be excluded.

**What would be the right regex for that ?**

In case it's important: I need this regex to run in Google Tag Manager with a "matches Regex" condition.

Thanks a lot.

I made some search but it's not answering my question properly because the usecases I've found are different.

Comment: What if it's `gform_180`?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [*alternation*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
gform_(18|23|11)
```